# Hololens-SpatialMapping (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm actually doing a project with the Hololens of Microsoft. The problem is that the Hololens memory is bad, so i can only make a spatialmapping of a room and not of a building because he can't remember all the building. I had an idea, maybe a can create more object and assemble them ? But no one talk about this... Do you think it's possible ?

Thanks for reading me.

Y.P

Comment: Short answer: nope. Long answer: Nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooppppppppppppppppeeeeeeeeee.

Comment: If you dial down the scan density, you can map out pretty large structures.  How big is the building you want to scan? (I can get a decent scan of all rooms plus garage of my 3-story house at default density.)

Comment: It's a big building, like 40 rooms. The problem is that I can't assemble two objects because I don't  know the "direction" I have to assemble because the hololens has no compass. He creates his repairs when he is starting. So every time the cords are changed... So maybe it exists another way to do it. I'm still locking !!

Comment: Walk through the entire area slowly. Fragments are not reassembled into a larger model. Models can be extended, as long as you have a known place to start from. I'd be curious te hear whether you succeed ;)

Comment: Already tried aha, yes of course I will send you a message if a succeed !

Answer (score 0):

Since you don’t have a compass, you could establish some convention to help. For example, you could start the scanning by giving a voice command (and stop it by another one), and decide to only start scanning when you’re facing north, for example. Then it would be easy to know the orientation of each room. What may be harder is to get the angle exactly right. Your head might be off by a few degrees and you may have to work some “magic” (post processing) to correct it.

Or placing QR codes on a wall (printer paper + scotch tape) and using something like Vuforia can help you avoid this orientation problem altogether (you would get the QR code’s orientation which would match that of the wall).

You can also simplify the scanned mesh and convert it to planes. That way you can remember simpler objects instead of the raw spatial mapping mesh. (Search for the SurfaceToPlanes script in the Holographic Academy tutorials).

Comment: Well I just noticed the question date... I hope it can still help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Scanning, the first layer, as in HoloLens trying to reason about the environment is an unstoppable process. There is no API for starting or stopping it. And that process also does slowly consume more and more memory as far as I know. The only thing you can do is deleting space (aka deleting holograms) or covering the sensors. But that's OS/hardware level, not app level, which you presumably want.

Layer two, what you are you probably talking about, is starting and stopping the spatial reconstruction process, where that raw spatial data is processed into a low-poly mesh (aka spatial mapping). This process can be started or stopped. For example through Unity's SpatialMappingCollider and SpatialMappingRenderer components, if you use Unity.

Finally the third level is extracting some objects/segments from that spatial mapping mesh into primitives. Like that SurfaceToPlanes. That you can also fully control in terms of when.

There has been a great confusion, especially due to the a re-naming parties in MixedRealityToolkit (overuse of word Scanning) and Unity (SpatialAnchor to WorldAnchor etc.) and misleading tutorials using a lot of colloquialisms instead of crisp terminology.

Theory aside. If you want the HoloLens to think of your entire building as one continuous space in terms of the first layer, you're out of luck. It was designed for a living room and there is a lot of voodoo involved into making it work stable in facilities 30x30 meters. You probably want to rely on disjointed "islands" with specific detection anchors to identify where you are. Or rely on markers and coordinates relative to them.

Cheers